# How will a rotating, circular, and cylindrical body of a superfluid develop in outer space?

Tags: rotation, superfluidity

Let's consider a rotating (about its center, in the plane cutting the initial circular and cylindrical form into two halves), circular, and cylindrical body of a [superfluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluidity) somewhere in outer space. Obviously, the fluid will never stop rotating (that's why I choose a superfluid instead of a normal fluid with viscosity).

How will the form of this body of superfluid evolve?

Will it because of centrifugal forces flatten out? Will rings emerge? Will different parts have different velocities after some time? Or will all the constituents parts move away from each other due to a lack of viscosity (like a vertical ray of water, under the influence of gravity, will be divided into droplets lower than a ray of honey, due to its lower viscosity? For sure some orderly form will develop.